# how to find host name from IP with out login to the host

Tags: unix, command-line, hostname

i need to find the host name of a UNIX host whose IP is known with out login to that UNIX host

Comment: NBTSTAT -A 10.10.10.10 for windows

Comment: Are you ever gonna accept an answer?

Comment: @PaoloStefan if the user is last seen in 2009 it's a highly improbable  event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get hostname from IP (Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182950/how-to-get-hostname-from-ip-linux)

Answer (score 171):

Use [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup)

```
nslookup 208.77.188.166 
...
Non-authoritative answer:
166.188.77.208.in-addr.arpa     name = www.example.com.
```

Comment: on centos installs, you'll need to run `sudo yum install bind-utils` first. this will install nslookup lookup for you

Comment: nslookup is deprecated. You could use 'dig' or 'host' instead

Answer (score 77):

You can do a reverse DNS lookup with `host`, too. Just give it the IP address as an argument:

```
$ host 192.168.0.10
server10 has address 192.168.0.10
```

Answer (score 45):

Another NS lookup utility that can be used for reversed lookup is `dig` with the `-x` option:

```
$ dig -x 72.51.34.34

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> -x 72.51.34.34
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12770
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1460
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;34.34.51.72.in-addr.arpa.      IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
34.34.51.72.in-addr.arpa. 42652 IN      PTR     sb.lwn.net.

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 25 21:23:40 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77
```

or

```
$ dig -x 127.0.0.1

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> -x 127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11689
;; flags: qr aa ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.                IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. 10      IN      PTR     localhost.

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 25 21:23:49 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

Quoting from the [dig manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig):

> Reverse lookups -- mapping addresses to names -- are simplified by the
>   **-x** option.  addr is an IPv4 address in dotted-decimal notation, or a colon-delimited IPv6 address. When this option is used, there is no
>   need to provide the name, class and type arguments.  dig automatically
>   performs a lookup for a name like 11.12.13.10.in-addr.arpa and sets
>   the query type and class to PTR and IN respectively.

Answer (score 27):

For Windows ping -a 10.10.10.10

Answer (score 19):

- For Windows, try:

  ```
  NBTSTAT -A 10.100.3.104
  ```

  or

  ```
  ping -a 10.100.3.104
  ```
- For Linux, try:

  ```
  nmblookup -A 10.100.3.104
  ```

They are almost same.

Comment: nmblookup worked great, I wasn't trying to find hostname of a web server, but computers that were doing things they shouldn't. This exposed not just the Windows Hostname, but the Mac address, which was next on my list!

Comment: there is no such package nmblookup in ubuntu. which linux are you refering to? did you mean "nslookup" for by any chance?

Answer (score 10):

```
python -c "import socket;print(socket.gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1'))"
```

if you just need the name, no additional info, add [0] at the end:

```
python -c "import socket;print(socket.gethostbyaddr('8.8.8.8'))[0]"
```

Comment: It says, invalid syntax highlighting socket.

Comment: for python3 change print to a function with parenthesis: `python -c "import socket;print(socket.gethostbyaddr('10.16.7.10'))"`

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the context. I think you're referring to the operating system's hostname (returned by `hostname` when you're logged in). This command is for *internal names only*, so to query for a machine's name requires different naming systems. There are multiple systems which use names to identify hosts including DNS, DHCP, LDAP (DN's), `hostname`, etc. and many systems use [zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#Name_resolution) to synchronize names between multiple naming systems. For this reason, results from `hostname` will sometimes match results from `dig` (see below) or other naming systems, but often times they will not match.

**DNS** is by far the most common and is used both on the internet (like `google.com. A 216.58.218.142`) and at home (mDNS/LLMNR), so here's how to perform a [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#Multiple_pointer_records): `dig -x <address>` (`nslookup` and `host` are simpler, provide less detail, and may even return different results; however, `dig` is not included in Windows).

Note that hostnames within a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) will not resolve to the canonical domain name (e.g. "google.com"), but rather the hostname of the host IP you queried (e.g. "dfw25s08-in-f142.1e100.net"; interesting tidbit: 1e100 is 1 googol).

Also note that DNS hosts can have more than one name. This is common for hosts with more than one webserver (virtual hosting), although this is becoming less common thanks to the proliferation of virtualization technologies. These hosts have [multiple PTR DNS records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#Multiple_pointer_records).

Finally, note that DNS host records can be overridden by the local machine via [/etc/hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). If you're not getting the hostname you expect, be sure you check this file.

**DHCP** hostnames are queried differently depending on which DHCP server software is used, because (as far as I know) the protocol does not define a method for querying; however, most servers provide some way of doing this (usually with a privileged account).

Note DHCP names are usually synchronized with DNS server(s), so it's common to see the same hostnames in a DHCP client least table and in the DNS server's A (or AAAA for IPv6) records. Again, this is usually done as part of zeroconf.

Also note that just because a DHCP lease exists for a client, doesn't mean it's still being used.

**NetBIOS for TCP/IP (NBT)** was used for decades to perform name resolution, but has since been replaced by LLMNR *for name resolution* (part of zeroconf on Windows). This legacy system can still be queried with the `nbtstat` (Windows) or `nmblookup` (Linux).

Comment: @John Syrinek Can you elaborate about DHCP hostnames query? I want to query the hostname of another machine(in the same wlan) by IP, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are correct - use reverse DNS lookups.
If you want to do it via a scripting language (Python, Perl) you could use the gethostbyaddr API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically looking for a Windows machine, try below command:

```
nbtstat -a 10.228.42.57
```

Answer (score 0):

For minimal distros/images with only [curl](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) installed for networking utilities:

```bash
curl --write-out '%{remote_ip}' localstack:4566
```

produces, e.g.:

> 172.18.0.3

**Note:**

In Windows the %-symbol is a special symbol used to expand environment variables. In batch files all occurrences of % must be doubled when using this option to properly escape. If this option is used at the command prompt then the % cannot be escaped and unintended expansion is possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use traceroute command as well.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute

just use the traceroute  it will show you the routing path with host names (IPs resolved)

Comment: See the comment by Ottavio Campana below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657482/how-to-find-host-name-from-ip-with-out-login-to-the-host#comment17837415_9059477

Answer (score -2):

In most cases, traceroute command works fine. nslookup and host commands may fail.

Comment: this is wrong: given an IP, the only thing to do is a reverse query to the DNS. Thus, traceroute it's not the correct tool to suggest.