# Getting Device Hostname

Tags: unix, networking

I have a unix machine on a network and I'm looking to get the device hostname for devices on that network. How do I go about doing this? I've tried nmap, arpscan, host, and nslookup but they all seem to want to do a DNS reverse lookup. I don't have a DNS server on the network.

When I say hostname I'm referring to the device name set by the user. So for example host on my machine returns joshcloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nbtscan for Windows devices. avahi for things that suppor zeroconf.

Otherwise check out the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the same answer I gave here: [How to get hostname from IP(Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182950/how-to-get-hostname-from-iplinux). Basically you're going to need to either add DNS entries or connect to each host individually and ask for names.