# Difference between Microsoft Bot Framework and Azure Bot Service?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I want to create a bot, but I am confused what is exactly Bot Framework and Azure Bot service? Can anyone explain in detail?

Comment: Have you gone through the docs?

Comment: yes I read some blogs,but I didn't understand properly. Can you explain high-level?

Comment: read the documentation it will easily explain this

Answer (score 8):

The best way to understand the difference is going through the docs. The Azure Bot Service documentation is available [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/).

In a nutshell, Azure Bot Service provides a set of templates to get started with the creation of Bots and accelerate the development since it provides an integrated environment. Of course, the templates that it creates are based on the BotFramework. With Azure Bot Service, you can even code your bot directly from the Azure Portal Editor, from the comfort of your browser.

If you don't want to start with Azure right way, and want to develop your Bot locally first, etc, you might want to use the BotFramework builder bits; but as I said; once you se Azure Bot Service, you are able to download the generated bot and continue the development from your machine if you want.

Comment: Thank you Ezequiel Jadib.
If I use Microsoft bot framework, what are all platforms to deploy the bot except Azure?

Comment: You could potentially use any platform as it just a rest api. Though it might not be as easy as with azure. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013866/connection-error-on-microsoft-bot-after-publishing-it-on-aws

Comment: @EzequielJadib, can you help me about code, downloaded from Azure BotService? I create azure bot, download code, but it is not compilable:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789201/can-i-modify-azure-bot-at-vs

Answer (score 6):

Admittedly you asked your question a year and a half ago, but in early 2018 it seems as though Microsoft uses the two terms interchangeably for one product.

Take, for example the documentation link from the [bot framework home page](https://dev.botframework.com/), the title of this page is *Bot Service Documentation*:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/

Also, in the [Azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) only Azure Bot Service is listed (under both "Analytics" and "AI + Machine Learning").  "Azure Bot Service" is what appears on the invoice.

Finally, when you go to create a new resource and search for "bot" the only related items that you will see are for Azure Bot Service, there is no mention of Azure Bot Framework there either.

Comment: To add to this, https://dev.botframework.com/ has the following notice posted `With the launch of the new Azure Bot Service, we are migrating all bots to the new service by 3/31/2018. Learn more about the migration. START MIGRATING`

Answer (score 2):

**Bot Framework** - is comprised of an open-source SDK and tools for end-to-end bot development.

**Azure Bot Services** - a cloud platform that hosts bots, helps you manage, connect, and deploy your bot across devices and popular channels

**Bot Framework Service** - a component of Azure Bot Service, that responsible to sending the info between the app and the channel

[Microsoft Bot Service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)