# What is the difference between creating a bot from the Azure portal, and from the Bot framework?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I can see that I can create a bot service and connect it with the Bot Framework right from the Azure portal? As far as I can see It creates a project, that is kind of different than the C# bot project in my Visual Studio.. then it gives me way to continuous integrate it with a remote repository, what exactly is this and how is this different from creating a project in the Studio, make a bot in the Bot framework website and just Publish it from VS? It says that it will create "some files to start with", but despite I select C# as a language I definitely don't see C# based project created.. 
[image: test]
Microsoft's support on this topic is very very poor..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Microsoft Bot Framework and Azure Bot Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865274/difference-between-microsoft-bot-framework-and-azure-bot-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It IS in fact a C# based project.  Please see [Debugging C# bots built using the Azure Bot Service on Windows](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/manage/debug/#debugging-c-bots-built-using-the-azure-bot-service-on-windows)

> The C# environment in Azure Bot Service has more in common with
>   Node.js than a typical C# app because it requires a runtime host, much
>   like the Node engine. In Azure, the runtime is part of the hosting
>   environment in the cloud, but you’ll need to replicate that
>   environment locally on your desktop.
>
> First, you need to set up your environment. You’ll need:
>
> 1. A local copy of your Azure Bot Service code (see  [Setting up Continuous Integration](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/manage/setting-up-continuous-integration/) )
> 2. The Bot Framework Emulator
> 3. The Azure Functions CLI
> 4. DotNet CLI
>
> and if you want breakpoint debugging in Visual Studio 15:
>
> 1. Visual Studio 15—the Community Edition will work fine
> 2. The Command Task Runner Visual Studio Extension

These are also requirements:

[Azure 2.9.6 .NET SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518003&clcid=0x409)
[Visual Studio Tools for Azure Functions](https://aka.ms/azfunctiontools)